# How to add extra folder in URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need add `/movimento` in all urls `/item*`

```
http://mareconteudo.com.br/item/o-que-vimos-no-content-marketing-world-copy-copy
```

i need:

```
http://mareconteudo.com.br/movimento/item/o-que-vimos-no-content-marketing-world-copy-copy
```

Same help me?

Comment: I like your recursive question format! Here's a link: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?item/ /movimento%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```